# how to extract byte literal from string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a array of string

```
["0b01001010", "0b01001010", "0b01001010", "0b01001010"]
```

How do I make it

```
[0b01001010, 0b01001010, 0b01001010, 0b01001010]
```

thx

Comment: AFAIK, Ruby has no mechanism for converting *anything* to a literal. Literals are for the parser, not for internal representation of objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can map the sequences to binary:

```
["0b01001010", "0b01001010", "0b01001010", "0b01001010"].map{ |e| e.to_i(2) }
# => [74, 74, 74, 74]
```

To map back:

```
[74, 74, 74, 74].map{ |e| e.to_s(2) }
# => ["1001010", "1001010", "1001010", "1001010"]
```

Comment: Great. I didn't know that `to_i(2)` works with `"0b"` prefix.

Comment: Alternatively `Integer("0b01001010")` notation can be used. See more on Numbers Literals [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
["0b01001010", "0b01001010", "0b01001010", "0b01001010"]
.map{|s| eval(s)}
# => [74, 74, 74, 74]
```

or

```
["0b01001010", "0b01001010", "0b01001010", "0b01001010"]
.map{|s| s[2..-1].to_i(2)}
#=> [74, 74, 74, 74]
```